# Clean way to make a php login script on a site with includes?

Tags: php

Basically I have an index.php file with navigation in form of includes *only*.

---

- My script can check whether a user exists by checking a database.
- It can also log you in if the check was successful.

My problem is **redirects**! Do I really have to use
`echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content=\"1; URL=index.php\">";`?

And I also have to make tons of if-statements to cover the entire possibilities of a users actions (have to take evil people into account).

Headers are already ruled out because I use includes and requires.

I'm on the brinck of switching to ASP.NET or something rediculous... This scripting is making me mad :P

Comment: It sounds like you are getting into websites that are a little too complicated to just be using includes and if statements. I would highly recommend investing the time to learn a framework (for example, CodeIgniter) to make your life much, much easier. It will handle a lot of this for you out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know such thing existed...

Comment: This is not the problem, your application architecture is, ASP.NET is programming, PHP is scripting, if you cant script how you going to manage to program ? sit back and have a cup of coffee man.

Comment: I like making things from ground and up... I feel I learn nothing if I just take some template and put it on my site.

Comment: If you want to learn more then I recommend you to watch/read those two tutorials: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/ and http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html They are not directly related to your problem but are more general about a possible structure (MVC pattern) you could put into your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you either need to use an existing content management system or framework or learn to code in a modular drop-in fashion.  Coding it for modularity would mean that the included script can be left out and the page still function as usual.

I'll post an example in a bit.

Just looked at your code.  The index page is insecure.  Do not do it like that.  I could do something nasty like index.php?p=../../../whateverfile and try to include it from outside of /inc/.  You need some sort of protection against user input.  Something like an array specifying valid files to include to check against, or a db table containing valid files to include that it can check against.

*edit*
Also, never ever store the password in a cookie.  You should generate a unique key or something for the login and store it and check against it instead of the password.

Here's what you'd want to do:  Split the login file up into checking logic and presentation.  Once you do that it means that the checking logic can be included anywhere on the page, while the form itself can also be placed anywhere.

Here's a little example:

`loginCheck.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{

     if(!$_POST['username'] || strlen($_POST['username']) <= 3 || strlen($_POST['username']) >= 20)  //Check user input for validity
     {
          $loginerror['username'] = "Username is required.  Must be between 3 and 20 characters long.";
     }
     if(!$_POST['password'])
     {
          $loginerror['password'] = "Password is required.";
     }


     if(count($loginerror) == 0)
     {     
          $username = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username'])); //Do whatever to the user input
          $password = mysql_reql_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

          $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `username`,`password`,`etc` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password' LIMIT 1");  //Select both at the same time

          if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
          {
               $loginerror['login'] = "Username or Password incorrect or does not exist.";  //It's smart not to let people know which they got wrong.
          }
          else
          {
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
               $loginmessage = 'Welcome ' . $username. ', you are successfully logged in';
          }
      }
 }
```

`loginForm.php`

```
function dispError($name,&$errors)
{
     if(isset($errors[$name]))
     {
          return '<span class="error">' . $errors[$name] . '</span>';
     }
     return '';
}

if(isset($loginmessage))
{
     echo $loginmessage;
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] === true)
{
     echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['username'];
}
else
{
     if(!isset($loginerror) || !is_array($loginerror))
     {
          $loginerror = array();  //Gotta make sure it exists for the next part if it hasn't been set.
     }
     echo dispError('login',$loginerror);
     echo '<form method="post" action="">';
     echo '<input name="username" placeholder="Username..." type="text" maxlength="15" />' . dispError('username',$loginerror) . '<br /><br />';
     echo '<input name="password" placeholder="Password..." type="password" maxlength="20" />' . dispError('password',$loginerror) . '<br /><br />';
     echo '<input name="login" type="submit" value="Login" style="width:100px;">';
     echo '</form>';
}
```

`index.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
     require_once("loginCheck.php");
}

//various other includes and requires

require_once("loginForm.php");
```

This way there's also no reason to redirect away from the login form/sign in page, as the checks can be easily included inline and both the form and the check can be included on any and all pages dynamically just by dropping it in where necessary.

Comment: I normally also use Rewrite Mod to make it more secure. But I can see your point...

Comment: When creating a user, it encrypts it using md5. But I guess that's not enough to make it secure?

Comment: No where near enough, no.  Never store it regardless of the hashing algorithm used to hash it.  md5 isn't that secure to begin with.  sha512 using `hash('sha512',$stringtobehashed)` would be better, but still don't store it anywhere.

Comment: Nice... I wanna learn more like that. But I don't wanna spend all day googling my way to it. Must be a faster approach or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

When you validate the user/login set a session variable

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

Then at the very top of each php file add the following code (You can put this code in a php file and use requires('thiscode.php')

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!loggedIn())
{
    header('Location: login.php');
    die();
}

function loggedIn()
{
    if($_SESSION['loggedin'])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: No, a SESSION variable is completely separate from a COOKIE variable.  I should've said if you use the above code you need to use the session_start command on your login page (must be the first line of php code and on any page using SESSION variables) but not anything else or you will get an infinite loop error

Answer (score 0):

You can probably still use the `header()` function, like this: `<?php header("Location: login.php"); ?>`
Make sure to add it before your include()s!

If not, post a snip-it of your code here, then I can analyse it.

Comment: Why can't you just add the header()s at the top?

Comment: At the top of which file? login.php is basically in the middle of index.php, so by putting a header at the top of login.php will basically mean it's in the middle of index.php!

Comment: @KristianB: It does not matter where in the PHP code the header function is called. As long as you do not output any HTML with echo/printf or directly as HTML in the file before.

Comment: You are using the location header wrong, it requires a fully qualified URI, not a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ob_start();`  // it makes you able to use headers anytime

make sure to put it on the first line and don't forget to add a `ob_end_flush();` at the end

for more information : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: I've tried ob_start() and it does indeed allow me to use header function more. But I also read that it's overkill to do it that way...

Answer (score 0):

> I have an index.php file with navigation in form of includes only.

....

> tons of if-statements

If you really must use a front controller architecture then try to at least make it data driven. You're simultaneously building a house of cards and a stick to beat yourself with.

> My problem is redirects! Do I really have to use....

No. Only if the rest of your code is a mess and you want to implement a PRG pattern too. And even then it's not necessary.

> Headers are already ruled out because I use includes and requires

Eh? That rather implies that your templating system is a mess.

> I'm on the brinck of switching to ASP.NET or

It's not going to make you a better programmer.

You've made a lot of conflicting choices about the architecture of your application and now you're finding that these don't all fit together as easily as you had expected.

Go have a look at some of the excellent PHP CMS and frameworks available - and see how they tackle these problems.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comments. I know I'm brilliant at all at this. But it will be my job when I'm finished with the next semester at school. So you're saying the way I let my site navigate is a mess?